# Angular Destroying a dynamically created component completely

Tags: angular, typescript, reference, components, destroy

I create a lot of dynamic components using:

```
this.factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(SliderComponent);
this.sliderComponentReference = viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.factory);
```

When I need the component destroyed I call the destroy method:

```
this.sliderComponentReference.destroy();
```

I understand that it deleted the dynamic component from the view and it's instance however when I view the variable right after I notice it still has information:

```
changeDetectorRef: ViewRef_ {_view: {…}, _viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef.. }
componentType:(...)
hostView: ViewRef_ {_view: {…}, _viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef... }}
injector:(...)
```

**Questions:**

1. How come the variable still has reference to the component instance if it was destroyed?
2. Is the component still stored in memory? If so is it retrievable?

Comment: By "view the variable right after" you mean `this.sliderRef.destroy(); console.log(this.sliderRef)`?

Comment: I created this [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mlc-app-init-n6wuuv) so anyone interested can see a running code example of what the OP is referring too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the component ref definition here: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/view/refs.ts#L103 -- it has the `changeDetectorRef`, `hostView`, etc. properties. When you call `.destroy`, it calls the underlying `viewRef.destroy` method: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/view/refs.ts#L277

This ends up calling other methods, but it doesn't seem to actually overwrite any of the properties that were already defined on the component ref. As far as I know in JavaScript, an object can't delete itself. You can only delete properties of an object with a reference to that object.

The component is still stored in memory and it is still usable in some sense. However, it may not work as you expect because of what `.destroy` does. You might be able to recreate it though ... and there are `attach` methods as well. JavaScript does its own garbage collection / memory management, so you can't really force these elements to be removed from memory. If JavaScript detects that the ref is no longer accessible by any pointers during a garbage collection cycle, it will free that memory.

Comment: let componentRef = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(cmptName).create(this.injector);this.dynamicComponentContainer.insert(componentRef.hostView);  I save componentRef in array, say, 'componentTracker' variable and we have 3 components in DOM. Can we destroy , a particular component using refrence stored in  'componentTracker'  ie  this.componentTracker[i].destroy();